# React, load main scripts dynamically depending on the domain

Tags: reactjs

We have more than 5 domains and use one server.
And we need to load scripts using CDN.
For example, site1.com should load from cdn.site1.com. site2.com should load from cdn.site2.com

The problem: reactjs generate files and URLs in building

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can load `script` dynamically by **creating the `script` element at run time**.

### Example

```
 componentDidMount () {
     if (location.host === 'google.com') {
         this.loadScript("script.js");
         this.loadScript("www.google.com/script.js");
     }
     else if... // here you can add conditions for other domain
   }


   loadScript(src) {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = src;    
        document.body.append(script); // appending script to body
    }
```

[You can find more here](https://github.com/suri66/JS-IN-EASY-WAY#6-add-script-dynamically)

Comment: What about hash? How can I know it? 
like this /css/main.chunk.7b31.css **7b31**

Comment: Sorry  @StanislauKaraliou not getting what you are asking about here? Why you asking about .css chunk here?

Comment: That's an example with hash in name file, we need to load CSS too But for example, we have files like /js/main.chunk.7b31.js. It adds a hash to files every deploy